# Can someone explain this bitwise C code?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I don't know what's going on with this:

```
#define _PACK32(str, x)                   \
    {                                             \
        *(x) =   ((int) *((str) + 3)      )    \
               | ((int) *((str) + 2) <<  8)    \
               | ((int) *((str) + 1) << 16)    \
               | ((int) *((str) + 0) << 24);   \
    }
```

the str it's a integer and the x it's a integer pointer

Comment: `str` is not an integer, I don't think it is.

Comment: The macro takes 4 bytes in big-endian format and combines them into a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: This really badly written, where did you find it? E.g `*((str) + 3)` is better written as `str[3]`. If it is really supposed to be a `char` array, then the conversion to `int` would be implicit, so the cast should really better be left out. It really could hide bad usage of this macro. Then using `{}` like that in a macro is really dangerous. Either use `()` or use `do { ... } while(0)`.

Comment: Should be `unsigned int` anyway since shifting into the sign bit.

Comment: @JensGustedt Also, if `str` points to `signed char` then all three shifts are undefined for negative chars, and if `str` points to `unsigned char` the shift by 24 is undefined for a different reason.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: If it's `unsigned char`, the shift by 24 is only undefined if the top bit of the unsigned char is set, which is never the case for 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: @EOF, I don't think this is necessarily an ASCII string. Nothing says so, and nothing prevents it not to be just arbitrary bytes in memory where `str` is pointing to.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I was just pointing out that this doesn't *necessarily* cause undefined behaviour. It's possible to use it in a well-defined manner.

Comment: @JensGustedt Well, *((str)+3) is a lii...iiitle bit faster than str[3] (i don't know why but everybody says that)

Comment: @FalconUA: Whoever this "everybody" is, he's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as mentioned, `str` is not an integer. It's a pointer, as it is being dereference with `*` operator.

`*((str) + 3)` is equivalent to `*(str + sizeof(str[0])*3)`, thus this depends on the type of str, as seen [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). Same goes for other dereference operator.

So what's going on? Well, it takes the least significant 8bit of str[0], str[1](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/), str[2], and assemble them to one 32 bit size integer.

For instance, let `W, X, Y, Z, A` be arbitrary bit. Then,

- `*(str + 3) = WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXX`
- `*(str + 2) = WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWYYYYYYYY`
- `*(str + 1) = WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWZZZZZZZZ`
- `*(str + 0) = WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWAAAAAAAA`

The last 3 are shifted, 8, 16, and 24, respectively, thus,

- `*(str + 3) = WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXX`
- `*(str + 2) = WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWYYYYYYYY00000000`
- `*(str + 1) = WWWWWWWWZZZZZZZZ0000000000000000`
- `*(str + 0) = AAAAAAAA000000000000000000000000`

Note that the least significant digits of the last 3 are replaced with 0 during the shift.

Last, they are OR'ED, which is then assigned to X,

`X = AAAAAAAAZZZZZZZZYYYYYYYYXXXXXXXX`

**Edit:** O'Ring is not as straightforward as it might seem seems W's could be anything.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Offsets 0, 1 and 2 are shifted. Offset 3 remains as is. The final value (if we assume that the `W` bits are 0) is: `XXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZAAAAAAAA`

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix Well, my eyes must've been upside, down. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `str` is a pointer to an array of 4 bytes, and `x` is a pointer to a 32 bit value. `str` would actually point to the first byte (LSB) of a little endian 32 bit number, and this macro would read it and store in the variable pointed by `x`.

Comment: Just want to ask: In big-endian case, all `<<` should be replaced to `>>`, right?

Comment: No, you would start with index `0` and finish at index `3`.

Comment: @FalconUA: No, the macro works for either representation of multi-byte ints and the string representation is always big endian. The macro converts a 4-byte big endian representation, probably read from an external source, to a native int, regardless of the platform's endianness.

Comment: The string representation is little endian, not big endian.

Answer (score 1):

Correctly written as an `inline` function this should look something like:

```
void pack32(void const*p, unsigned* x) {
    unsigned char const* str = p;
     *x = str[0];
     *X = *x<<8 | str[1];
     *X = *x<<8 | str[2];
     *X = *x<<8 | str[3];
}
```

you should use unsigned types when you do bit shifting, otherwise your result can overflow. And perhaps it also makes the idea clearer. The suposedly 8 bit of each byte are placed in the different bits of the target `x`.